# Python - How to replace None values in a numpy array with the median of adjacent elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I generated an array with missing data

```
A = np.zeros((80,80))
for i in range(80):
    if i%2 == 0:
        for j in range(80):
            A[i,j] = None
            if j%2 == 0:
                A[i,j] = 50+i+j
    else:
        for j in range(80):
            A[i,j] = None
            if j%2 != 0:
                A[i,j] = 50+i+j
```

Which gives me this below screenshot.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is replace all "None" values with the median of the adjacent elements which aren't None values as well.
Is there an easy way to do this without going through every element in a loop ?

Comment: maybe you can use masked arrays ? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Answer (score 0):

I've written something like this (even though it was for masked arrays but I quickly adapted it for NaNs) based on `numba`.

As Ami Tavory has said you can also do it with some numpy tricks but I mostly find it is clearer (if there is no builtin) if you write the loops yourself and then optimize it. I've chosen numba because even though it is limited in some aspects it is very well suited for speeding up such `for` loops.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def median_filter_2d(array, filtersize):
    x = array.shape[0]
    y = array.shape[1]
    filter_half = filtersize // 2
    # Create an empty result
    res = np.zeros_like(array)
    # Loop through each pixel
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            # If it's not NaN just let it stay
            if not np.isnan(array[i, j]):
                res[i, j] = array[i, j]
            else:
                # We don't want to go outside the image:
                start_x = max(0, i - filter_half)
                end_x = min(x, i + filter_half+1)
                start_y = max(0, j - filter_half)
                end_y = min(x, j + filter_half+1)

                # If you want to use nanmedian uncomment this line and comment everything else following
                #res[i, j] = np.nanmedian(array[start_x:end_x, start_y:end_y])      

                # Create a temporary array.
                tmp = np.zeros(filtersize*filtersize)
                counter = 0 # Counter because we want to know how many not-NaNs are present.
          
                # Get all adjacent pixel that are not NaN and insert them
                for ii in range(start_x, end_x):
                    for jj in range(start_y, end_y):
                        if not np.isnan(array[ii, jj]):
                            tmp[counter] = array[ii, jj]
                            counter += 1
                
                # Either do it with np.median but it will be slower
                #res[i, j] = np.median(tmp[0:counter])
                # or use some custom median-function
                res[i, j] = numba_median_insertionsortbased(tmp[0:counter])
    return res
```

The helper median function is just an insertion-sort based sorting which then returns the middle element or the mean of the two middle elements.

```
@nb.njit
def numba_median_insertionsortbased(items):
    # Insertion sort
    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and items[j] < items[j-1]:
            items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]
            j -= 1
    # Median is the middle element (odd length) or the mean of the two middle elements (even length)
    if items.size % 2 == 0:
        return 0.5 * (items[(items.size // 2)-1] + items[(items.size // 2)])
    else:
        return items[(items.size // 2)]
```

If you don't want to use `numba` or cannot you can just delete the `@nb.njit` lines and use it in pure-python. It will be a lot slower but it will still work.

For an 80x80 `A` I get timings with numba:

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop (custom median)
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.88 ms per loop (numpy median)

but for large filtersizes the numpy median will be a bit faster since they (hopefully) have more advanced methods than insertionsort. But for your array the elements will be sorted in the temporary array so the insertionsort based median is clearly best suited. For real images it will probably be slower than the numpy median.

and pure python:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 406 ms per loop (custom median)
>
> 1 loop, best of 3: 707 ms per loop (numpy nanmedian without the inner loops and the temporary array)
>
> 1 loop, best of 3: 832 ms per loop (numpy median on temporary array)

As aside: I always find it surprising that something like that custom median even without numba is faster than the numpy median for small 1D inputs (ok, they are already sorted so it's the best case of insertionsort :-) ):

```
%timeit numba_median_insertionsortbased(np.arange(9)) # without the @nb.njit
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.7 µs per loop
%timeit np.median(np.arange(9))
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 µs per loop
```

and that these even faster solutions can be speed up even more with numba:

```
%timeit numba_median_insertionsortbased(np.arange(9)) # WITH the @nb.njit
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.93 µs per loop
```